# Hash Map Algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hashmap

The assignment is to count the number of times a letter shows up in a word by using hashmaps. Ex: "cats" should be {'c' => 1, 'a' => 1, 't'=>1}, so why isn't the what I've written working? Thanks in advance!

```
def letter_count(str)
  i=0 
  letters = {}
  while i<str.length 
    letters[str[i]]=0
    i+=1 
  end
  puts letters
  letters.each do |letter, number| 
    j=0 
    while j<str.length 
     # puts letters[str[j]]
      if letters[str[j]] == letter
        puts "something happens"
        number=number+1 
      end
      j+=1 
    end 
  end
  letters.delete(" ")
  puts letters
  return letters
end
```

Comment: You are overcomplicating! Try to study Ruby core and make this smaller.

Comment: Your code is very procedural, very un-Ruby-like. Don't worry, you'll soon have an "aha" moment, after which writing code the Ruby way will seem both natural and liberating.

Comment: You posted basically the same question on CS.SE (http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66651/755), and got the feedback over there that [debugging your code is off-topic on CS.SE and probably off-topic everywhere on the Stack Exchange network](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66651/755).  20 seconds after that comment, you posted here.  I'm not sure why you posted here after you were previously told that posting here is probably off-topic.

Comment: Anyway, as our [help] states: "Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."  "why isn't my code working?" does not describe a specific problem or error and thus does not count as a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

You modify `number`variable (its just variable not poiter to the hash value) inside loop and its not possible to do it this way.
Another problem is `letters[str[j]]` will never have same value as `letter` because `letters` return `Integer` (count in this case 0) not a `String`.

So you can modify your code like this:

```
def letter_count(str)
  i=0
  letters = {}
  while i<str.length
    letters[str[i]] = 0
    i+=1
  end
  puts letters
  letters.each do |letter, number|
    j=0
    while j<str.length
      # puts letters[str[j]]
      if str[j] == letter
        puts "something happens"
        letters[letter] += 1
      end
      j+=1
    end
  end
  letters.delete(" ")
  puts letters
  return letters
end
```

will produce

```
letter_count("cats")

# something happens
# something happens
# something happens
# something happens
# => {"c"=>1, "a"=>1, "t"=>1, "s"=>1}
```

**But more redable and simple example:**

```
def letter_count(str)
  str.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |char, hsh|
    hsh[char] += 1
  end
end

letter_count("cats")
# => {"c"=>1, "a"=>1, "t"=>1, "s"=>1}

letter_count("tests")
# => {"t"=>2, "e"=>1, "s"=>2}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
def letter_count(str)
  tmp_hash = {}
  str.split('').uniq.each do |letter|
    tmp_hash[letter] = str.count(letter)
  end

  puts tmp_hash
  return tmp_hash
end
```

output

```
word = 'hello'
letter_count(word)
# output: {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "o"=>1}
```

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to use `each_with_object({})`. Also don't call print/puts in the method definition. Print when calling the method.

Comment: Yes, I've learned recently that initializing a hash like in `tmp_hash = {}` to use in a block is a code smell in Ruby. `#each_with_object` would surely be a better way. `#inject` is also a possibility.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida how would you do this with `#inject`?

Comment: Haven't tested the idea, @sagarpandya82. Something like **`str.split("").inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,letter| ...}`**, I think. Gonna try it later. Busy now.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida In case (like me) you didn't manage to figure out a way, Cary has kindly posted a method with `inject` in the comments to his answer.

Comment: You see? It is possibe! I was missing that "h" in the end.

Comment: Without that "h" in the end, the block won't return the hash to iterate the next step.

Answer (score 2):

One way for a string defined in `str`:

```
Hash[str.chars.group_by(&:itself).map { |k,v| [k, v.count] }]
```

key methods: [String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-chars), [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-count)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a *counting hash*.

```
"muddled".each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> { 'm'=>1, 'u'=>1, 'd'=>3, , 'l'=>1, 'e'=>1 }
```

See [Hash::new](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), particularly in reference to *default value* as an argument of `new`. Ruby expands `h[c] += 1` to

```
h[c] = h[c] + 1
```

before processing the expression further. Suppose

```
h = Hash.new(0).merge('d'=>2)
  #=> {"d"=>2}
```

Then

```
h["cat"]
  #=> 0
```

because does not have a key `'cat'` and `h`'s default value is zero. Now suppose `c = 'd'`. Then

```
h['d'] = h['d'] + 1
   #=> 2 + 1 => 3
```

so

```
h #=> {"d"=>3}
```

Next, if `c = 'm'`, because `h.key?('m') #=> false`, `h[c]` on the right of the equality returns `h`'s default value, zero.

```
h['m'] = h['m'] + 1
   #=> 0 + 1 => 1
```

Note that the method [Hash[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) on the left of the equality is not the same as the method [Hash[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) on the right side.

I could have instead written

```
"muddled".each_char.with_object({}) do |c,h|
   h[c] = 0 unless h.key?(c)
   h[c] += 1
end
```

or

```
"muddled".each_char.with_object({}) { |c,h| h[c] = (h[c] || 0) + 1 }
```

If you are unfamiliar with [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) it produces the same result as the following, at the expense of two additional lines of code.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
"muddled".each_char { |c| h[c] += 1 }
h
```

Comment: Cary, is there a way to do this with `inject`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, certainly: `"muddled".each_char.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,c| h[c] += 1; h } #=> {"m"=>1, "u"=>1, "d"=>3, "l"=>1, "e"=>1}`. Old-timers report that before [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (aka `reduce`) made its debut in Ruby v1.9, `inject` was used where `each_with_object` is used now. Note that the order of `inject`'s block variables is reversed relative to `each_with_object`'s, and that pesky `; h` at the end of `inject`'s block is not needed with `each_with_object`.

Comment: Interesting ty. The `h` was my undoing, have I feeling I won't forget it next time for sure.

Comment: This was the point I was missing. The "h" in the end, so that it could return the hash to the next step!